# I can't get my css to link properly with my php file

Tags: html, css

Right now I'm working on a school project where I create a bookstore. I have created the front page and now I'm trying to use php to create the login and register system. I've created the Register page (php) and I created a CSS File to go along with it, however I can't get the two to connect properly. When I run it in localhost the css won't render. I don't see a error in my code and I don't understand why it's not working. I tried to change the css name around a bit to see if the problem was the naming however nothing else seems to work.

```css
/* Import Google Font */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora&display=swap');
.form-div {
  margin: 50px auto 50px;
  padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #80ced7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <Meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--Bootstrap 4 CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Other CSS File --->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="registerandlogin.css" type="text/css">

  <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Register Today and Join the Royal Reader Community</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <form action="signup.php" method="post">
          <h3 class="text-center">Register</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="passwordConf">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="passwordConf" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="signup-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-log">Sign Up</button>
          </div>

          <p class="text-center">Already a member?</p><a href="login.php">Sign In</a>




        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your signup.php stored and where is your css stored?

Comment: Check if the css is loaded in your browser console, probably you have an error in your css path

Comment: Is the CSS file in the same directory as your sighup.php?

Comment: they are both stored in the same folder htdocs/RoyalReader

Comment: No hidden file endings like .txt behind .css? The name of the css file is correct?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah, I've checked, they both show up in the localhost/RoyalReader folder however the css doesn't appear  I have ran both files into code validators, for the CSS I used the W3C CSS Validation Service, I can't find any errors and on brackets it doesn't show any errors either. My homepage and the other css file I used for that page both loaded perfectly, this is the only one that's giving me problems

Comment: There is no element with the class form-div so it has no effect. Try that add class="form-div" to your form

Comment: @RobinGillitzer yeah I just checked both of their properties signup ends in .php and registerandlogin ends with .css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a class to your form or whatever like this:

```
<form class="form-div" action="signup.php" method="post">
```

Here you can read about css selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: yes that solved my problem, I see where I was going wrong now. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an element named `.form-div`, which is why your CSS does not affect anything. Try adding an element with that class name in your `<form>` tag.

Comment: It doesnt have to be a div.